# What is meant by "functions with a variable number of parameters"?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

In C, what is meant by "functions with a variable number of parameters"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is a nice example of that :)

```
printf("Call with no other variables");
printf("Call with %d variables", 1);
printf("Call with %d variables. The other variable: %d", 2, 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

It means a function that can accept a variable number of arguments:

```
void myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
    {
    }
```

You can call the above function in any of the below manners:

```
myprintf("This is %d", 1);
myprintf("%d out of %d", 1, 2);
myprintf("%d/%d %c", 1,2, 'c');
```

Answer (score 1):

It refers to a function which can take a variable number of parameters using ellipses (...) in the parameter list and va_list, va_start, va_arg etc methods/macros.  Do you have a more specific question about it?

See for example:

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_arg/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks all , but can anybody explain it with a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

A function which takes variable number of arguments. Eg `printf`
The signature is as `<return-type> <function-name>(<datatype>,...);`

Answer (score 0):

It denotes those functions, which have parameters but the number of parameters are not fixed (hence variable no of params).